# How to display an image partially in flutter to get a curtain-raising effect?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to display an image in flutter such that it gives an effect of curtain-raising animation based on the slider values.

For example, I am displaying the IMAGE.jpg which has a fixed height and width on the flutter app.

The slider has 0 to 10 range.

- When 0: the slider value is 0 then the image layout area is displayed 100% black.
- When 1: Bottom 10% is displayed and the top 90% is black
- When 2: Bottom 20% is displayed and the top 80% is black

and similarly

- When 10: 100% is displayed

How can this effect be created?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO. Please update the question by sharing some of your code which would make it easier for the SO community to answer your question. Cheers!

Comment: You can either clip the image or show another widget on top of it using a Stack that hides the widget below partially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create this curtain effect you can use the [Slider](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) and [Align](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widgets. You can set `heightFactor` inside the `Align` class to create a percentage curtain effect. Inside the `Slider` widget you can now set the value of the `heightFactor` to create the curtain effect.

Here a minimal working example:

[image: Slider Curtain Demo]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: CurtainScaffold());
  }
}

class CurtainScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CurtainScaffoldState createState() => _CurtainScaffoldState();
}

class _CurtainScaffoldState extends State<CurtainScaffold> {
  double curtain = 0.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Slider(
              onChanged: (double val) {
                setState(() {
                  this.curtain = val;
                });
              },
              value: curtain,
              min: 0.0,
              max: 1.0,
            ),
            ClipRect(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                heightFactor: curtain,
                child: Image.network(
                    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Dts_news_bill_gates_wikipedia.JPG'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```